# How to let the latest message persist on redraw?

Tags: redraw, message

The problem I have is, for example, when using undo (`u` in normal mode) or redo, sometimes the message, like

```
1 change; before #520  09:20:15
```

stays, but more often it flickers for a split second and is then erased. Then I have to go to `:mess` to read it.

The reason seems to be that the message is erased whenever the window is redrawn. (Because in cases when the line above isn't erased, if I resize the gVim window, it causes a redraw and the message disappears at that point.)

I think it would be better if the latest message were displayed until something else starts happening in the message/command line, as opposed to on redraw. But I can't find any pointers to help change that behaviour.

Comment: Probably a plugin `redraw!`ing, I don't think this is normal.  Do you use any plugins which might be doing this?

Comment: @Mass I moved the contents of my `$VIM/plugin`, `$VIM/autoload`, `vimfiles/plugin`, `vimfiles/autoload` directories temporarily to a different place, restarted gVim, and it's still happening. Hard to say what is causing the redraws, but it's a common event: even scrolling using the scrollbar or the mouse wheel causes a redraw.

Comment: Sure, a resize causes a redraw. Why do you do that, if you want to read the text?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt The aim is for the text to remain visible after redraw.

Comment: There is no way around it. You might want to check `lazyredraw` option, but I doubt this will work. Once you resize the Vim window, it must be redrawn.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt What I mean is that the resizing is not central — it's just an easy way to cause a redraw. The aim of the question is for the last message to persist _across_ redraws. I suspect that undo/redo in particular (but this is also not central) sets off redraws under certain conditions (maybe when more lines become visible or when the cursor jumps around in the file, not sure), but this happens more than half the time, in my use. I should probably read the source ... when I get around to it...

Answer (score 3):

Not really what you want but you can still redirect messages to a split with such a command:

```
:redir @">|silent messages|redir END|split|put
```

Just map it to a shortcut that suits you.